# Private MediaWiki wiki and a bot to create pages

Tags: database, mediawiki, wiki, bots, wikipedia

I have a private wiki running in localhost. I use MediaWiki 1.19 and I have to insert nearly 100 pages in MediaWiki's database.

I've tried pywikibot but it doesn't work: I've got trouble about login. I've spent a few hours without finding where is the problem.
I've tried the MediaWiki bulk creator: when I run the php script, all seems ok but no page is created.

Do you know if a bot can be used with the MediaWiki's last version in localhost?

Maybe I can write to the database directly? The documentation isn't very clear about that.

Have you got any idea to create pages automatically? Or do you know a bot (any langage accepted) that works with the latest version?

Comment: Pywikipediabot works fine with private wikis. It is, however, not easy to identify the problem when all the information you give is "doesn't work".

Comment: I've got trouble with login Login failed. Wrong password or CAPTCHA answer? as you can see here : http://pastebin.com/9xabzAQ6. I spent hours to this problem and can't find a clue about that.

Comment: Could you paste your family file and an example view and edit URL for the wiki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [maintenance/edit.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aEdit.php) command-line script if you're on the same machine, don't change the database manually.

Answer (score 0):

lilawood's own answer: In "maintenance" directory, we have all we need to edit or import page from file:

- edit.php : Edit a page to change its content
- importTextFile.php : Import the contents of a text file into a wiki page

Tested and approved! It can easily replace pywikibot.
Hope it helps.